# mysql querying a database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question as to a better way of doing this as I have a very large database with a lot symbols. "Hence a, aa... etc"
I would like to know if I can actually query every table also desc order would be nice. In one line. Otherwise I will have to type thousands of unions and it will be a pain later as the database will be changed often. As a table is erased and another joins it place. 
Every table has the Date column and would like to search based on a date.
Thank you in advance. 
I.E.

```
SELECT * from a where Date = '2017-07-31'     union
SELECT * from aa where Date = '2017-07-31'    union
SELECT * from aaap where Date = '2017-07-31'  union
SELECT * from aabvf where Date = '2017-07-31' union
```

Comment: That sounds like a horrible database structure to work with! May I ask why it's like that?

Comment: You can make a query first `SHOW TABLES` to list all of the tables, then after extracting the list, create a loop with a query for each table

Comment: @matthew.mason: Can you post the schema of a single table assuming they're all the same?  I read through the comments and don't see a reason they can't all be in the same table with the addition of an auto_incrementing primary key and a covering index that includes symbol and date and optionally a deleted flag.  If you're worried about concurrent writes, InnoDB helps a lot.  You've already got a multi-threaded feeder -- it could write CSV files that you could load into MySQL to avoid index thrashing if you're worried about it.

Answer (score 0):

I mean, you COULD....

```
SELECT * FROM a,aa,aaap,aabvf WHERE date='2017-07-21'
```

Comment: See I tried that. Error I get in the webpage is... Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 86
0 results

Comment: I also tried it in the console in phpmyadmin and get #1052 - column 'Date' in where clause is ambiguous.

Comment: Even so. If this method does work. I want to avoid the typing of a, aa, etc in general and basically have a way of basically updating it on the fly if say I delete a table. Instead of going through the a, aa .. etc list and deleting it.

Comment: You can't select from something without adding them in. You could do a schema grab , like show tables. Use that sql result to create an array, then loop through each table, add it to a query by appending them to a string, then do it that way but it's not super secure

Answer (score 0):

Ahmed helped me out. As to why my data structure is like that. Well. If you have better suggested I'm opening to it. So.
Why.
Basically I have data in the form of symbols
I.E. A, AA that are stock tickers
They have dates that are unique keys to open, high, low, various other stock measurements.
So why I would want to grab just a single date. It's basically the top date or "today" to display and chart. So I can do various other things with the data.
If you have another method of storing I'm open.
I written a java program (not normally a web developer) that mines the data and that form and stores how I suggested. Which I could change, if you have a better way. I would love to hear. Also. If you have opinion on how to store data faster with MySQL I would love to hear. Currently I have few hundred threads that basically store data. Each thread handles a symbol. It creates a table if it doesn't exist with the ticker name and puts its data in columns separated date (unique key) open, high, etc... also various other operations the incoming data and stores that. Thank you for the answer and thank you if you have a better method !

Ps sorry I didn't mean chart. I display the top date as a table with corresponding data attached!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your answer does **not** address the question -- it asks another question. Please try to avoid asking new questions in answers, as they are likely to be deleted or down-voted (costing you reputation). If you are having a similar issue, you can [**search for similar questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/search) or [**ask a question of your own**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). If it helps to clarify your own question, you can link to this question, or you can mark it as a favourite by clicking on the star to be notified of any new answers.